# Make ssh-keyscan use the .ssh/config settings

Tags: ssh, command-line

Is there a way to use the `~/.ssh/config` file with the `ssh-keyscan` command?  My tests are showing that this is not working, but perhaps there is a setting or something that would allow it?

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: What options from the config file would you like ssh-keyscan to use?

Comment: any / all of them, but of specific importance is user and port

Answer (score 1):

See [ssh-keyscan does not read .ssh/config?](https://serverfault.com/questions/943774/ssh-keyscan-does-not-read-ssh-config)

> ssh-keyscan doesn't and cannot be made to use .ssh/config.